# Removing duplicate files in a given directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-system

The following code is a python script that removes duplicate files in a given directory. At first I considered the most basic thing: relying on identical names, but you might have 2 different files with the same name in 2 different directories. So I decided to rely on md5checksum, since any 2 files that yield the same md5checksum almost invariably have the same content.

```
#A simple Python script to remove duplicate files...Coded by MCoury AKA  python-scripter
import hashlib
import os

#define a function to calculate md5checksum for a given file:
def md5(f):
    """takes one file f as an argument and generates an md5checksum for that file"""
    return hashlib.md5(open(f,'rb').read()).hexdigest()

#define our main function:
def rm_dup(path):
    """relies on the md5 function above to remove duplicate files"""
    if not os.path.isdir(path):#make sure the given directory exists
        print('specified directory does not exist!')
    else:
        md5_dict={}
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):#the os.walk function allows checking subdirectories too...
            for f in files:
                if not md5(os.path.join(root,f)) in md5_dict:
                    md5_dict.update({md5(os.path.join(root,f)):[os.path.join(root,f)]})
                else:
                    md5_dict[md5(os.path.join(root,f))].append(os.path.join(root,f))
        for key in md5_dict:
            while len(md5_dict[key])>1:
                for item in md5_dict[key]:
                    os.remove(item)
                    md5_dict[key].remove(item)
        print('Done!')

 if __name__=='__main__':
    print('=======A simple Python script to remove duplicate files===========')
    print()
    print('============Coded by MCoury AKA python-scripter===================')
    print()
    print('===========The script counts on the fact the fact=================')
    print('=========that if 2 files have the same md5checksum================')
    print('==========they most likely have the same content==================')
    print()
    path=input(r'Please provide the target path\directory... for example: c: or c:\directory...')
    print()
    rm_dup(path)
```

Ever since discovering the Zen of python I became obsessed with using the least possible lines of code. Plus I have another (and perhaps more serious) concern; calculating md5checksum for large files takes precious memory real-estate right? Could that limit the functionality of the script? Also, what do you think of the implementation?

Comment: Python prefers readability over density of information. This idea is included throughout the Zen of Python. I don't know how you read it as 'you should minimise your code'.

Comment: Don't use md5. Just. Don't.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use md5?

Comment: Please don't add another version of the code to the question after it has been answered. I've rolled back Rev 5 → 2. [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 5):

To get md5 of large files you can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3431838/2634676):

```
def md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()
```

Now here

```
for f in files:
    if not md5(os.path.join(root,f)) in md5_dict:
        md5_dict.update({md5(os.path.join(root,f)):[os.path.join(root,f)]})
    else:
        md5_dict[md5(os.path.join(root,f))].append(os.path.join(root,f))
```

I see two things:

- You don't need to check if key in your dict, you can use `defaultdict` instead
- `md5` is calculated twice per each file, first time to check if it's in dict, second time to actually add it to dict.

Here:

```
while len(md5_dict[key])>1:
    for item in md5_dict[key]:
        os.remove(item)
        md5_dict[key].remove(item)
```

You can just use `list.pop()`

So in the end your code should look like this:

```
import hashlib
import os
from collections import defaultdict


def md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()


def rm_dup(path):
    """relies on the md5 function above to remove duplicate files"""
    if not os.path.isdir(path):  # make sure the given directory exists
        print('specified directory does not exist!')
        return

    md5_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):  # the os.walk function allows checking subdirectories too...
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_md5 = md5(filename)
            md5_dict[file_md5].append(filepath)
    for key in md5_dict:
        file_list = md5_dict[key]
        while len(file_list) > 1:
            item = file_list.pop()
            os.remove(item)
    print('Done!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('=======A simple Python script to remove duplicate files===========')
    print()
    print('============Coded by codereview.stackexchange.com AKA python-scripter===================')
    print()
    print('===========The script counts on the fact the fact=================')
    print('=========that if 2 files have the same md5checksum================')
    print('==========they most likely have the same content==================')
    print()
    path = input(r'Please provide the target path\directory... for example: c: or c:\directory...')
    print()
    rm_dup(path)
```

however there is one more thing, while in general it's right to first list all the files and then delete them one by one, because maybe in future you will add some option for user to select files he want to delete. In this current case you can just use set to keep md5 checksums in it, and delete files as soon as you fight one with the same chucksum.

P.S. two files with the same checksum are not 100% guaranteed to be the same. Think about adding some additional check.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! And thanks for solving the memory problem! How likely is it to find 2 files with different content but identical md5 checksum? What additional checks would you suggest?

Comment: If you want to _really_ check that they are the same, they are guaranteed to not be the same content if they **both** A) Have the same hash, _and_ B) Have the same **length** (i.e. file size).  This is because hashes do not collide for inputs of the same length.

Comment: Appreciated! Just incorporated checking file size by using os.path.getsize(file).

Comment: @Tersosauros: `This is because hashes do not collide for inputs of the same length.` Uh, since when? As far as I know this is entirely possible and for most common hashes no guarantee whatsoever. It's very *unlikely*, that's true, but it's not a guarantee. The larger a file, the more possible outcomes, the more likely a collision with a file of the same size (where 'more likely' here should be seen in relative meaning). For files of a few bytes you can brute-force and ensure no collisions (and any good hash won't have any) but large(r) files of exact same length *can* cause collisions AFAIK.

Comment: @robull really? 2 inputs of the exact same length (down to the last byte) can yield the same checksum? Doesn't that contradict the point of hashing? Any other checks to ensure uniqueness?